# Redirecting a page w/sessions

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have a PHP file that a user is directed to once they purchase a file from PayPal. It starts a session:

```
<html>
//Thank you message
</html>
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["token"] = uniqid();
    file_put_contents("token.txt", $_SESSION["token"]);
    include("purchased.php");
?>
```

That PHP file should redirect to this PHP file to start the download of the file:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION["token"])){$allowed = false;}
    else{
        $allowed = true;
        $token1 = $_SESSION["token"];
        $token2 = file_get_contents("token.txt");

        if($token1 == $token2)
        {
            $file="song.mp3";

            if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit;
            }
        }
    }       
    session_unset();
?>
```

However, if I copy and paste the URL to the first file, my download automatically starts (the second file runs soon after the first file) because I cannot figure out the best way to code the first PHP file. I know I'm doing something wrong. Help?

Comment: Don't think you can hide the URL at all as long as you are redirecting the user to that URL..

Comment: [*"@Fred-ii-. Instead of policing people's questions and tearing them down, why don't you... I don't know... try helping them out and providing some insight TO the question? Thanks. – Michael Allen Moore"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509223/starting-a-download-once-redirected-w-sessions?noredirect=1#comment76012572_44509223) - I didn't particularly like that comment. I'll tell you what; flag your other (now deleted repost of this question) to a moderator and see what they say. I doubt they're going to fence on your side. Stack makes the rules, we/I don't, remember that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, for a client side event, you need to have the file path in the content. But one thing you can do is using AJAX, if you send a request for getting the file path, let's say:

```
getContent("path.php", function (res) {
  // res will have the file path, say, http://file.php.
  window.location.href = res;
});
```

> **Note:** `getContent` - pseudo code for AJAX Get request similar to jQuery's `$.get()` implementation.

This gives you a better way of hiding. Still, not much, but kinda better. You must need server side validation using Sessions or Cookies, before downloading, which makes it the right way!

Use a simple user management, and when the user is logged in, the `session_start()` will be there in every page and the session will be set. In the download page, you can do something like:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION[user])) {
      die("Not Authorised!");
    }
    // Rest of the download code.
?>
```

For a simple user registration, you can follow my tutorial [Making an Affiliate Registration with Hierarchy](https://blog.praveen.science/challenge-making-an-affiliate-registration-with-hierarchy/) on this.

Comment: There's no login. The user clicks a PayPal button on my site, which directs them to PayPal's site where they can buy the mp3. When the purchase goes through, they should be redirected back to my site, which is when the download should begin. My PHP code allows for the automatic download when I redirect the user to it, but the user is not directed back to my website; they remain on the PayPal site. So the redirection involves sessions/cookies?

Comment: @MichaelAllenMoore Have come across this situation... Just thinking... Give me a few moments...

Comment: @MichaelAllenMoore Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571491) works?

Comment: Thank you for that article. I didn't even consider the "unsound application logic" part of it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar [*"Houston, we have a problem"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453417/redirecting-a-page-w-sessions#comment76012669_44453417) as per [this original from their (now deleted) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509223/starting-a-download-once-redirected-w-sessions?noredirect=1#comment76012572_44509223).

Answer (score -1):

You should rather do that with a session. Create a session and when the user buys the track, add a token to the session. The file.php then checks whether there is a valid token and if so, it serves the file.

So it would work similar to this:

After the user has purchased the file (you will probably get some result of the payment method you are using, like if the payment was successful or not), you generate a token in the PHP file the user is redirected to, which also shows the "thank you"-message.
At first, you have to start a session in said file:

```
session_start();
```

You can generate a simple token like this for example:

```
$token = uniqid();
```

The token will look somewhat like this: `4b3403665fea6`.

After that, you have to save the token on the server (with MySQL for example) and then set it into the session:

```
$_SESSION["token"] = $token;
```

And then in the `file.php`, you have to start the session at the top as before:

```
session_start();
```

Then you check if there is a token in the session. If not, set some temporary variable which we will use to check whether the download is allowed, to false. If it is, then you fetch the token from the session:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["token"])) {
    $allowed = false;
} else {
    $allowed = true;
    $token = $_SESSION["token"];
}
```

After that, you only have to compare the string in `$token` with the token you have saved at the server before. If there is a token on the server that matches with the string, set `$allowed` to true. And then only execute the rest of the code if `$allowed` is true.

Comment: Thank you. I am sure this will work; I understand the process. However, the only thing I'm worried about now is the potential fraud on the PayPal side of things. I found an article that seems to walk me through how to deal with that (i.e. make sure that my file was actually paid for), and then I can possibly use this solution as an added fraud prevention measure. Thank you again.

Comment: @MichaelAllenMoore No problem. If you have any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: I tried to go through the PayPal integration documentation, and it's super confusing. I'd rather see if I can securely send downloads via a regular PayPal button.

That leads me to my question: After PayPal payment, the user will be directed to my webpage that offers the download. Would sessions  prevent that URL from being copied and pasted (which would automatically trigger the download)?

Comment: @MichaelAllenMoore The session containing the token allows you to make sure only people who have said token (i.e. bought it) will be able to download it because only then the download part of the script is run. So in theory, yes. You should make sure a token gets invalid after the download tho.

Comment: Okay. So I've ultimately decided to just use a standard PayPal button. This button, when clicked, redirects the user to the PayPal site. They navigate through the payment details and buy the file on PayPal's site, then they're directed back to my site to download the file. So, after doing a little research before coming up with another question, could I start the session soon after the user is redirected to my page and set that session's lifetime to a small time limit? I don't know if your solution accounts for an external shopping cart so that is why I ask.

Comment: Yes, that should work the. Don't forget to de-validate the token on the server once the download has happened, however. Or else, the user will be able to download the file multiple times if they are fast enough.

Comment: You know what? I've been overthinking it. Your originally proposed solution makes sense. Let me see if I'm following the logic: the User is redirected to a PHP file which will display the thank you message. I generate a unique token in that file and store it. Then that file will "redirect" to another PHP file, which will start another session. If there is a token in that session, then grab it and compare it with the stored token; if they match, run the download script. If not, or if there is no token in the session, don't run it. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @MichaelAllenMoore Yes, that's pretty much right. Just one thing: you don't start a different session, you merely restart the already existing one. The naming is a bit confusing but `session_start()` only initiates the session and tells PHP that the session is used in that file.

Comment: Oh... so I only start the session in my "file.php"? And in your solution is "download_token" the same as "token?"

Comment: You don't really have to start the session. Even though the function is called `session_start()`, it only tells PHP that a session is active and it enables the use of the `$_SESSION`-variable. And also, yes, "download_token" is the same as "token". I missed that but I fixed it now. Thanks.